# Подсчитать сумму полей внутри дерева

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм

Есть таблица с полями id(int), name(text), parent(int) и value(int), как подсчитать сумму value свою и всех детей? Через mysql или вывести дерево вложенных массивов и считать как-то внутри рекурсивно?

Comment: вам чтобы получить "дерево массивов" надо все равно вытащить из БД все нужные данные, дак какой смысл перекладывать это на пхп и писать дополнительный код, если можно просто к запросу добавить `sum ` ?

Comment: в mysql нет возможности запросом пройти рекурсивно по всему дереву. или писать процедуру, или выносить на клиентскую часть в код. или, если глубина вложенности заранее известна, написать запрос на все уровни.

Comment: неизвестна вложенность, в том и проблема

Comment: Можно сделать линейную связь через создание поля path, где будет изложена вся цепочка связей для отдельной записи типа .12.554.16223, заполнив сначала её. И уже потом подсчитывать сумму через SUBSTRING('.%TOP_PARENT%.')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215744/1216425 в помощь

Comment: Версия MySQL? Если 8, то он знает про рекурсивные СТЕ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  (t1.value + SUM(t2.value)) AS sum
FROM
  table AS t1
  LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
GROUP BY
  t1.id
```

Comment: Вложенность неизвестна к сожалению, от 3 и больше уже не срабатывает

Comment: Тогда только вытаскивать всю базу и рекурсивно считать